# How can I store a text file in a stack using fstream

Tags: c++, file, stack, fstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   stack <fstream> webpages;
   fstream web1;
   fstream web2;
   fstream web3;

   web1.open("web1.txt",fstream::out);
   web2.open("web2.txt",fstream::out);
   web3.open("web3.txt",fstream::out);

   web1.close();

   webpages.push(web1);
   cout << webpages.size() << endl;

   system("pause");
}
```

When I compile the program I get the following error:

> std::basic_fstream>::basic_fstream(const
>   std::basic_fstream> &): attempting to
>   reference a deleted function

so I assume the way I am doing this is wrong. Is there a way I can store fstream files in a stack?

Comment: `When i run the program and error` - what is the error?

Comment: `std::basic_fstream` objects are non-copyable, so you can't do what you're trying to do. With C++11, you can use `std::move` to move your `std::fstream` objects into `std::stack`.

Comment: Depends on the size of the file and the stack area. You probably can't store a text file on the stack because stack memory area is small.  Try "memory mapping" the file instead.

Comment: Can you store the names in the stack and open and append to the files as required?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think the asker is asking about `std::stack` not stack as Automatic storage.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not talking about `std::ifstream` but declaring a local array of characters large enough to contain the content of a text file.  This is my understanding of storing a file on the stack.

Comment: @SergeyA
'std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::basic_fstream(const std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: That's the deleted copy function Yksisarvinen talked about.

Comment: @KaranVadhan Just out of curiosity: Did you ever try out the solution I proposed in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to store the text in the files on your stack and not the actual fstream objects? If so, it will be easier to store the content of the files as strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stack <std::string> webpages;
    for(const auto& file : {"web1.txt", "web2.txt", "web3.txt"}) {
        std::fstream page(file);
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << page.rdbuf();
        webpages.emplace(ss.str());
    }
    std::cout << webpages.size() << "\n"; // will print "3"

    std::cout << "-- pages read --\n";
    for(;!webpages.empty(); webpages.pop()) {
        std::cout << webpages.top() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Edit: As pointed out, it really looks like you want to open some files for writing, so here's a version for that.

```
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::stack<std::fstream> webpages;

    for(const auto& file : {"web1.txt", "web2.txt", "web3.txt"}) {
        webpages.emplace(file, std::fstream::out);
    }

    for(;!webpages.empty(); webpages.pop()) {
        webpages.top() << "some text\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of this. The Asker opens the files for writing, not reading.